# How can I enable VSCode auto import suggestion for a deep path import from a shared UI library in an NRWL NX repo?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import, autosuggest, nrwl-nx

I wish to ask some help for setting up NX repo with VSCode import suggestion from a shared UI library

I am setting up an NX repo for my next.js project by the following commands:

```bash
npx create-nx-workspace nx-next-import-suggest --packageManager=yarn
# > Integrated monorepo
# > next.js
# > SASS

yarn nx generate @nx/next:library shared-ui-next-lib --no-interactive
```

I wish to auto import components from `shared-ui-next-lib` when coding in the app folder (i.e. `apps/nx-next-import-suggest/app/page.tsx`)

Specifically, I want to import the components by deep path, e.g. `import { Button } from '@shared-ui-next-lib/Button'`
so I added the following in `tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
    "paths": {
      "@nx-next-import-suggest/shared-ui-next-lib/*": [
        "libs/shared-ui-next-lib/src/lib/*"
      ]
    }
```

It actually works! But…

> *I have to manually write the following import statements*
> `import { Button } from '@shared-ui-next-lib/Button'`
> *If I start with writing `<Button` and expect VSCode to suggest the above import statement for me, it just does not do so*

[image]

How can I make the import suggestion work?

Example repo here:
https://github.com/ecchochan/nx-next-import-suggest

---

The best I can do is to export the component one by one in the outmost `index.ts`
But it still does not suggest the deep path :S

[image]

---

The reason I wanted to import by `import { Button } from '@shared-ui-next-lib/Button'` and avoid `import { Button } from '@shared-ui-next-lib'` is that:

> I expect a deep import will make the bundle size smaller (by not importing all the components, that a new small next project do not use)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have the same setup in my repository as well as this lib does not have private parts (shared components, utils functions).
Using `nx:lib` without barrel file was way to go for me as I don't want to reexport everything from **index.ts**.
What helped me is depicted below using your library name and directory structure.
I also got rid of the `lib` folder in my setup.

1.Modify `tsconfig.base.json` **paths** section

- this enables to use the @ (scoped import)

```
"paths": {  
  "@shared-ui-next-lib/*": ["libs/shared-ui-next-lib/src/lib/*"]
}
```

2. Modify your application `tsconfig.json` **include** section

```
"include": [
   "../../libs/shared-ui-next-lib/src/lib/**/*.ts*"
]
```

- be aware that this settings basically enables you to also import code using `libs/...` and breaks the idea of `nx:lib` and barrel files (public/private parts of library)